# Reading MS Word file via python

Tags: python, file, cpu-word

I tried to parse the text field (a special object in MS Word for text selection) using python-docx, but it seemed like this module doesn't have such a functional. Has anyone encountered such a problem? Maybe there are other ways to parse word-files?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check out this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ms-word-documents-using-python-ed3fbb48c122

Comment: Thank you very much! It's pretty long way, but it works!